# std::function from "new" and type

Tags: c++, c++14

Let's assume I have the class Class.

Now I'd like to create a std::function<Class*()> object which creates a new object of type Class, uses the default constructor and returns it.

Is there some extremely simple way to bind new with a type and be done with it?

Or do I have to make a function/lambda that does it and bind to it?

```
std::function<Class*()> getCreateFunction()
{
  return std::bind(operator new) // somehow tell new what to allocate ?
}
```

---

I do know how to solve this with a lambda. I'm just curious if I didn't realize something obvious about how bind and new would work together.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this ?

Comment: I'm just curious if I'm being dumb by not realizing something that should be obvious with bind and new. I do know how to make this with a lambda or a separate function.

Comment: for me the only advantage of `bind` was that there was no alternative. For most cases this advantage is gone since there are lambdas

Comment: I was referring to the purpose of `getCreateFunction()`. What's your use case that makes `Class::getCreateFunction()()` preferable over `new Class()` ?

Comment: I'm making a deserialization thing that needs to create objects based on class identifiers, this is just a simplified part of the code i'm writing.

Comment: the only reason to wrap a constructor call into a `std::function<Class*()>` i can think of is that you have other functions that return `Class*` and you want to use both. If you just need to call constructors of different objects then I don't see the point. Btw not saying that the quesiton itself is moot, I just don't get the motivation behind (and maybe thats for a different question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind` takes a callable entity as the argument.

`new Class()` is an [expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#1). An expression can't be "called". To make an expression "callable", it can be wrapped in a lambda. But then you don't need `std::bind` anymore.

Comment: Note: you can bind to `operator new(size_t)`, but it won't create an object of type `Class`, it will only allocate memory.

Answer (score 2):

It's like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct Class {};

std::function<std::unique_ptr<Class>()> getCreateFunction()
{
  return &std::make_unique<Class>;
}
```

You don't need `std::bind`, as there are no parameters to bind to.

Comment: Ok, yeah. I do actually use unique_ptrs I just removed them from the question to simplify it. Very good, thanks! However the accepted answer is in line with the question I wrote..

Comment: A textbook example of why we shouldn't "simplify" away specific details of your use case!

Answer (score 1):

Why `std::bind()`?

What about

```
std::function<Class*()> getCreateFunction ()
 { return [](){ return new Class{}; }; }
```

Off Topic Suggestion: starting from C++11, when possible, avoid direct management of allocated memory and use, instead, smart pointers.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks:

> I'd like to know if there is a way to make this happen with bind and new.

If you really want to pass through `std::bind()`, you need a callable of some type (the first and only mandatory argument of `std::bind()`).

So you can write

```
std::function<Class*()> getCreateFunction ()
 { return std::bind([](){ return new Class{}; }); }
```

But... frankly... excluding the case of a code obfuscation contest... I find this solution a little silly.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to make a lambda. I was just curious if there was some other way.

Comment: Call it professional curiosity, I'd like to know if there is a way to make this happen with bind and new.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d - Answer improved. Well... improved... answer modified.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. I was just wondering if I could bind what new allocates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are looking for "simple **or** lambda", because I consider using a lambda the most simple (cases where you need to resort to `bind` are rare):

```
#include <functional>
struct Class {};

std::function<Class*()> getCreateFunction()
{
  return [](){ return new Class; };
}

int main() {    
    Class* c = getCreateFunction()();
}
```

I hope in your real code you return a smart pointer not a raw one. Using raw owning pointers and bare `new` isn't nice, hiding it deeply is even less nice.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda tried to say that I know how to use a lambda to solve this, I'm just curious if there was some simple way of doing it with bind.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d using a lambda is the simple alternative to using `std::bind`.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d - To do it with `std::bind()` you need a function or something callable: `return std::bind([](){ return new Class{};});`. But this seems to me a little silly.

Comment: Yeah, I've been hearing this a lot: people don't like lambdas. They consider them to have a lot of boiler plate and would prefer function pointers and mem_fn and such. Apparently it's hard to make the switch.

Comment: @JHBonarius I rather have problems with `std::function`. It feels too powerful for most use cases and I try to avoid it when I don't really need it. Lambdas on the other hand play very well with common optimizations.

Comment: @JHBonarius • those people have an odd position.  Lambdas eliminate tons of syntactical boilerplate.  But if they'd rather write all that boilerplate explicitly... well... *shrug* okay.

Comment: Nah, i wasn't even talking about `std::function`. More like the &class::func type of calling. `std::function` has it's own problems, with the (possible) dynamic allocation involved.

Comment: What on earth are you guys on about, I have no problem with using lambdas. I was just asking out of professional curiosity.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d don't panic. I don't think the comments were specifically targeted at you or your question. I was picking a bit on your wording in my answer, but thats just my way of reading questions and answering them.